# Acrobat Extending Fields

Tags: pdf

I am trying to search how to make a expendable field in acrobat. Means i have some data and i want to organize it in a way so that on first glance only important data will be shown but additional information can be accessed if you will click the near by button.

For ex:-

page have this information.

---

**This year's whole production is 200 units.** 
list of products
**Total consumption is 190 units.**

---

but after clinking "list of product" it will show the page like below

---

**This year's whole production is 200 units.** 
list of products

**X type products = 50 units

Y type products = 100 units

Z type products = 50 units**

**Total consumption is 190 units.**

---

Any comment or suggestion is welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: As max indicates in his answer, that is possible if you restrict yourself using certain viewers. But in my opinion you should reconsider your choice of format. Pdf predominantly is a format for fixed contents looking the same everywhere, not for dynamic contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

According to Adobe Propaganda, you would need an XFA form for that (created with LiveCycle Designer). There you can specify a field to be growing according to its contents.

However, it is also possible to do it with PDF forms (using AcroForms). You may have to take some precautions, but it can be done.

One of the field properties is rect, which consists of the coordinates of the top left and the bottom right corner point of the field. With this you can programmatically change the size of the field.

In your case, you would have to figure out by how much you would have to stretch the field to properly display all the additional information; you may have to analyze the additional text at runtime and then determine by how much you have to stretch. You will also have to refresh the field value after changing the field's size.

And that's about it.

Note that this feature works only with PDF viewers understanding Acrobat JavaScript.

Comment: *this feature works only with PDF viewers understanding Acrobat JavaScript.* - considering the number of pdf (pre) viewers out there without JS support, i would not introduce the answer with *This is possible.* But with **this is impossible unless you restrict yourself to use a viewer supporting JS.**

Comment: With all due respect, PDF viewers which do not understand Acrobat JavaScript are, if they are used with forms, simply useless. Also keep in mind that the newest draft of ISO 32000 does contain JavaScript, and therefore, those viewers do not fulfill even the core of ISO 32000.

Comment: In addition to the lack of support of JavaScript, chances are rather high that these viewers are crappy anyway (not displaying documents correctly, for example; not honoring overprinting is a common issue).

Comment: Still, the op's question does not indicate that he merely talks about js-enabled viewers. He should clarify.